# Facebook SDK: incorrect login behaviour. Push safari login window in session state "open"

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

Situation:
Person login in FBApp but not login in System FB account.

What I do:
I ask `readPermissions` and `publishPermissions`. After that I send request for person identity (id,name,username,profile_picture_url).

Behaviour:
Everything works fine, facebook ios sdk go to fb app twice (for each request - read and publish) and after that miracle appears.
I request for person identity and see facebook window, which suggest to download fb app for iPhone (fb app've been already on it!) and ask me to login on website. I think that this is a safari login appears.

Code:

```
/*login here*/
            if([_facebookSession state] == FBSessionStateCreated){
                [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:readPermissions allowLoginUI:YES completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState status, NSError *error) {
                    if (error || status == FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed){
                        [_facebookSession openWithBehavior:FBSessionLoginBehaviorWithNoFallbackToWebView completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState status, NSError *error) {
                            if (error || status == FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed){
                                LoginFailedBlock(YES);
                            }
                            else
                            if (error == nil && status == FBSessionStateOpen){
                                _facebookSession = session;
                                LoginSucessBlock(YES);
                            }
                        }];
                    }else{
                        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_current_queue(), ^{
                            [FBSession openActiveSessionWithPublishPermissions:publishPermissions defaultAudience:FBSessionDefaultAudienceFriends allowLoginUI:YES completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState status, NSError *error) {
                                if (error == nil && status == FBSessionStateOpen){
                                    _facebookSession = session;
                                    LoginSucessBlock(YES);
                                }
                            }];
                        });
                    }
                }];



/*request for person identity*/
/*SOMEWHERE HERE A SAFARI LOGIN WINDOW APPEARS*/
     [FBRequestConnection startForMeWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id<FBGraphUser> result, NSError *error) {
            if (error){
                ErrorBlock(error);
            }
            else{
                if ([result id] && [result name]){
                    NSDictionary* resultDictionary = @{@"id":result.id,
                                                       @"name":result.name,
                                                       @"username":result.username,
                                                       @"picture":result.link,
                                                       };
                    AfterLoadUserInfoBlock(YES,resultDictionary);
                }
                else{
                    AfterLoadUserInfoBlock(NO,nil);
                }
            }
        }];
```

Answer (score 0):

in view controller :

```
self.loginview = [[FBLoginView alloc] init];
self.loginview.frame = CGRectMake(-500, -500, 0, 0);
[self.view addSubview:self.loginview];
self.loginview.delegate = self;
[loginview setReadPermissions:@[@"basic_info",@"email"]];
[loginview setDelegate:self];

 -(IBAction)loginWithFB:(id)sender{
    for(id object in self.loginview.subviews){
        if([[object class] isSubclassOfClass:[UIButton class]]){
            UIButton* button = (UIButton*)object;
            [button sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        }
    }
}
```

in appdelegate :

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
         annotation:(id)annotation {

    // Call FBAppCall's handleOpenURL:sourceApplication to handle Facebook app responses
    BOOL wasHandled = [FBAppCall handleOpenURL:url sourceApplication:sourceApplication];

    // You can add your app-specific url handling code here if needed

    return wasHandled;
}
```

then please register your application in developer.facebook.com with your bundle id finally you will get one id and configure in your plist file